# How to ensym to evaluate twice?

Tags: r, rlang

I am writing a function that logs different things. If the user does not provide an object name, I want to infer it. I found out I can use `ensym` to get the name of what the object was binded to.

Since I have several functions I want to use this on, I want to have it in its own function. But when I pass the object to the second function,`ensym` does not give what I need anymore.

The following function returns `test_data`, but I want it to return `starwars`

```r
starwars = dplyr::starwars

get_obj_name <- function(obj) {
  var = rlang::ensym(obj)
  print(as.character(var))
}

test_fun <- function(test_data, hej = NULL) {
  if (is.null(hej)) {
    get_obj_name(test_data)
  }
}


test_fun(starwars)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown by Allan, your `get_object_name(x)` is essentially just `deparse(substitute(x))`, and there is comparatively little benefit to wrapping that into its own function. In fact, Allan’s solution is idiomatic R.

Furthermore, wrapping this into its own function is a lot more complex than just copying the `deparse(substitute(x))` part, since `substitute` is performing non-standard evaluation in a specific context and is not referentially transparent.

However, I do believe that there’s a benefit to encapsulating the entire expression (including the `if (is.null(hej))` check into its own function if you find yourself using this pattern very frequently. And R *can* do this. So here is how I would suggest rewriting your `test_fun`:

```r
test_fun <- function (test_data, hej = NULL) {
  hej <- arg_label(test_data, hej)
  …
}
```

Note that I changed the name of your `get_obj_name` function to better reflect the fact that it works on *argument* names (it won’t work on other variables). (I also removed the unnecessary prefix `get_` which is implied here, and just adds clutter.)

Here’s the implementation:

```r
arg_label <- function (arg, label, caller = parent.frame()) {
  if (is.null(label)) {
    deparse(do.call("substitute", list(substitute(arg), caller)))
  } else {
    label
  }
}
```

The detour via `do.call("substitute", …)` ensures that the argument name is retrieved in the context of the *caller*, instead of the current context.

Adding the optional parameter `caller` is unnecessary but ensures that this function can still be used in a deferred context, i.e. where we provide the environment of the caller explicitly. I recommend *generally* adding such an argument to functions that use non-standard evaluation in the caller’s context.

Comment: `do.call` is exactly what I am looking for, I was sligthly annoyed that I could not specify a frame.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably reinventing the wheel here. This use case is fairly common in base R and is normally handled by `deparse(substitute(x))`. Instead of writing `get_object_name`, which is essentially just `deparse(substitute(x))` you could have:

```r
test_fun <- function(test_data, hej = NULL) {
  if (is.null(hej)) deparse(substitute(test_data))
}

test_fun(starwars)
#> [1] "starwars"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is how I do it but to be fair I still think there's value to encapsulating the entire expression `if (is.null(hej)) deparse(substitute(test_data))` in its own function. `testthat::quasi_label` does something *similar*, but not quite.

Comment: I understand the sentiment, and if there was just one function using this, I would probably do it like that. But I need the flexibility to make changes to it, so I disagree that I am reinventing the wheel. But I am curious to the difference between deparse and ensym in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I think you already need to defuse the function argument and create a quosure when calling `get_obj_name`. The following works:

```r
starwars = dplyr::starwars

get_obj_name <- function(obj) {
  print(rlang::as_name(rlang::quo_get_expr(obj)))
}

test_fun <- function(test_data, hej = NULL) {
  if (is.null(hej)) {
    get_obj_name(rlang::enquo(test_data))
  }
}

test_fun(starwars)
#> [1] "starwars"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

As far as I understand what happens here:

- you need to capture the calling environment when trying to defuse an expression -> this is recorded in the quosure
- if you use `ensym`(or more general, `enquo`) only in `get_obj_name`, the symbol of the expression is `test_data`, as the calling environment is `test_fun`
- to capture the original symbol, you already need to generate the quosure in `test_fun`. Now, you can pass around the quosure as much as you like and infer the symbol where ever you like (e.g. you could pass `obj` to another function and only there infer the symbol
- because here the expression is only one variable name (of which you want to know the symbol), you can use `quo_get_expr`

Comment: You don’t need to call `rlang::quo_get_expr` explicitly with `rlang::as_name` (you *do* need it with `rlang::as_string`). And at that point `get_obj_name` becomes redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the info about `quo_get_expr`. Yes, I agree that the short function doesn't make much sense, I assumed that the function is only the MRE and would a bit more.